# ui-sref not working in cordova android app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router

I am building an android app using cordova. Am using angularjs ui-router for routing. ui-sref is not at all working. Below is my code:

```
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', [
  'ui.router',
  'ngTouch',
  'angular.filter',
  'angularApp.services',
  'angularApp.controller',
]);

angularApp.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
          templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    })
    .state('settings', {
      url: '/settings',
          templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
  });
```

The home state loads by default, and when I click on the link for settings, it isn't working.

Here is the code in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"> -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
        <!-- Path to Framework7 Library CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.material.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/framework7/css/framework7.material.colors.min.css">
        <base href="file:///android_asset/www/" target="_blank">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angularjs-app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/framework7/js/framework7.min.js"></script>
        <div id="welcome-wrap">
            <div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"/></div>
            <div class="preloader"></div>
        </div>

        <div ng-include="'templates/common-left-panel.html'"></div>

        <div class="views">
          <!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class-->
            <div class="view view-main">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <div class="left">
                            <a href="#" class="link icon-only open-panel"> <i class="icon icon-navicon"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="center">
                            <h3>app</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <a href="#" class="link icon-only search-icon"> <i class="icon icon-search"></i></a>
                            <a ui-sref="settings" class="link icon-only setting-icon"> <i class="icon icon-gear"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Main page content with bottom tab bar  -->
                <div class="pages navbar-fixed">
                <a href="#/settings">Settings</a>
                    <div ui-view></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework-app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you setting the ng-app property? e.g: __<body ng-app="angularApp">__

Comment: I actually bootstrap angular on cordova deviceready event. document.addEventListener('deviceready', function onDeviceReady() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['angularApp']);
}, false);  
Isn't enough?

Comment: It should work. Just for be sure, put a __console.log("test")__ above __angularApp.config__ and see if the log works

Comment: Yes, the log works, but ui-sref doesn't change the url. Irrespective of the state, the ui-sref should change the state right?

Comment: Yes. The default __home__ view is loaded at the start or it doesn't?

Comment: Home view is loading by default, but the other state isn't loading on clicking the link

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `Content-Security-Policy` meta element in your html `head` tag.

Something similar to this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: ; connect-src * data: blob: filesystem:; font-src * 'self' filesystem: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src * 'self' filesystem: ; img-src * 'self' data: filesystem: ; frame-src 'self' gap://*">
```

Please see [this link](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/cordova-security-whitlists/) for more information on the proper security choices in your situation.